# error when i'm trying to delete an image used in a picturebox

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox

I'm using visual studio 2013 to create a c# windows application and I'm facing this error.

When I'm trying to delete an image that I have been using in a picturebox this error message appears..:

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\ALI PC\Documents\My Projects\Doctor Clinic\Doctor
>   Clinic\Images\1.jpg' because it is being used by another process.
>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode)    at
>   Doctor_Clinic.Forms.ReportForm.deleteBtn_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in c:\Users\ALI PC\Documents\My Projects\Doctor
>   Clinic\Doctor Clinic\Forms\ReportForm.cs:line 94

```
var file = @image;
using (var s = new System.IO.FileStream(file, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    PatientImage.Image = Image.FromStream(s);
}
PatientImage.Image = null;
PatientImage.Image.Dispose();
System.IO.File.Delete(file);
```

Comment: refer to this link. https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1236626/The-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-b

Comment: this link is for vb.net i'm using c# @AjayKumar

Comment: bro then you should add a vbNet label in your questions as well.

Comment: @progahmed The framework is the same, though, so the exceptions and solutions are identical. Just the programming syntax is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title is misleading. The line that throws is not the `Delete` but the `Dispose`.

You have already set it to `null`, so you can't `Dispose` of it any more. Use this instead:

```
   ..
   if (PatientImage.Image != null)
   {
      Image dummy = PatientImage.Image; 
      PatientImage.Image = null; 
      dummy.Dispose(); 
   }
   ..
```

First we store a new dummy reference to the image; then we clear the reference from the control and finally we use the dummy reference to free the GDI resources.

This is also recommended whenever you want to set a new `Image` to a `PictureBox`.

(This looks a little more complicated than one would expect when dealing with **reference** variables; but that is **not** what `PictureBox.Image` is. It is a **property** with all sorts of extras going on behind the scenes..)

Comment: it's done , thanks a lot , and i'm sorry for my bad English .

Comment: Shouldn't the dispose of a null object just have throws a nullpointer exception, and not an IO exception, though?

Comment: There's another issue in here, though. The image is assigned from a file stream inside a `using` block. That's not right; according to specs [the stream has to remain open while the image lives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2). To get around the locking issue, you can read the bytes of the image into a byte array, create a `MemoryStream` from that, and simply leave that stream open. Being a stream based on a system array, and not some external object like a file, this is apparently perfectly all right in terms of garbage collection.

Answer (score -2):

You have your image used by another application on your machine or by another running job.
To be sure that no one is using the image restart your pc and retry. If that doesn't work check the permission of the file