# C# loading lots of images to picturebox but it takes too much memory

Tags: c#, memory, picturebox

This is my code to load 100 images from MySQL database to a `Panel`,
and each of the image is about 28 KB.
However, the resource monitor shows that it takes more than 2 GB of memory,
and sometimes it leads to `out of memory exception`.

```
for (int x = 0; x < Topic4Number; x++)
{
   ReaderKeyword.Read();

   pbTopic4[x] = new PictureBox();
   if (x == 0)
   {
      pbTopic4[x].Location = new Point(45, 75);
   }
   else
   {
      if (pbTopic4[x - 1].Right < 1300)
      {
         pbTopic4[x].Location = new Point(pbTopic4[x - 1].Right + 35, pbTopic4[x - 1].Top);
      }
      else
      {
         pbTopic4[x].Location = new Point(45, pbTopic4[x - 1].Top + 445);
      }
    }
    pbTopic4[x].Size = new Size(Topic4pb_width, Topic4pb_height);
    pbTopic4[x].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    
    if (ReaderKeyword.HasRows)
    {
       long len = ReaderKeyword.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, 0);                           
       byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
       len = ReaderKeyword.GetBytes(0, 0, buffer, 0, (int)len);
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
       Bitmap img = new Bitmap(ms);                            
       pbTopic4[x].Image = img;                           
     }
}
PanelAll.Controls.AddRange(pbTopic4);
```

I did use `.Dispose()` to free the memory once I don't need those `PictureBox`.

```
if (pbTopic4 != null)
{
   for (int x = 0; x < Topic4Number; x++)
   {
      pbTopic4[x].Dispose();
      pbTopic4[x] = null;
      GC.Collect();
   }
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is there any way to reduce the memory used?
2. Is there any way to improve my code so that it can work faster?
3. Why it takes that much memory to show the `PictureBox`?

Comment: Try without `Zoom`.

Comment: _each of the image is about 28 KB._ Well that is meaningless. How large are the images? (In pixels) That will detemine the RAM needed, 3 or 4 byte per pixel. Also: Disposing of the PBox doesn't dispose of the Images, afaik. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754206/error-when-im-trying-to-delete-an-image-used-in-a-picturebox/57754802#57754802) - Btw the Zoom should not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for point out the problem of pixels. I looked up some information about creating thumbnail of the images and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I made some modification about creating thumbnail of the images, the program works faster and takes much lesser memory.

```
public bool ThumbnailCallback()
{
   return false;
}
```

```
if (ReaderTopic4.HasRows)
{
   long len = ReaderTopic4.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, 0);
   byte[] buffer = null;
   buffer = new byte[len];
   len = ReaderTopic4.GetBytes(0, 0, buffer, 0, (int)len);
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
   Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback = new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
   Bitmap img = new Bitmap(ms);
   Image myThumbnail = img.GetThumbnailImage(353, 250, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
   pbTopic4[x].Image = myThumbnail;
 }
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0